# asp.net dropdownlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I select a value from the dropdownlist, I like that value to be save in the @TimeZone value that is needed for

```
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Companies] ([TimeZone]) VALUES ( @TimeZone)"
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Here is my code:

Within my page load, I have the following code that assigns value to the drop down:

```
    ddlTimeZone.DataSource = from p in TimeZoneInfo.GetZones()
                             select new { p.Id };
    ddlTimeZone.DataTextField = "Id";
    ddlTimeZone.DataValueField = "Id";             
    ddlTimeZone.DataBind();
```

Next, within my .aspx file, I have the following:

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

..... .....

```
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Companies] ([TimeZone]) VALUES ( @TimeZone)"

     <InsertParameters>                 
         <asp:Parameter Name="TimeZone" Type="String" />           
     </InsertParameters>
```

Again, what I need to know is how to I bind the selected value from the dropdownlist (ddlTimeZone) to @TimeZone

I tried:

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TimeZone") %>' runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

But that did not work. NOTE THAT I AM USING THE DROPDOWNLIST WITHIN  A GRIDVIEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Companies] ([TimeZone]) VALUES ( @TimeZone)", connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TimeZone", valuetopass));
```

Comment: I need to do this within the aspx file as I  have more than 20 other columns that I also binding. How d I keep this in the aspx file and not the code behind

Comment: If you need to code in `.aspx` page, please have a look this example about [Using inline code in ASP.NET](http://www.808.dk/?code-aspnet-inline)